# updating react component when props change

Tags: javascript, react-native, components

I have a React Native Component which takes an image URI as a prop. I'm passing the prop from another js file:

```
<SlideComponent
imageUri={listOfAssets[counter].uri}      
/>
```

As you can see, the passing of the image URI is dynamic (maybe it's not the smartest solution, but it works kinda). The problem is that when the counter goes up and should technically provide a new image URI, the image won't update within the "SlideComponent".

This is how I update the counter variable:

```
const keepImage = async () => {
    counter = counter + 1;
  };
```

Is there a way to rerender the Component everytime the counter goes up?

Comment: Is `listOfAssets` a state variable? If not, that could be your problem

Comment: Which slider component are using? By default changing the props should update the component, but if the library has memoized the component to ignore prop updates you may have a problem

Comment: @tstrmn listOfAssets is a useState variable

Comment: @PhantomSpooks i'm passing the prop to a component using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-swipe-gestures

Comment: I assume it's a change of `counter` which you're expecting to trigger the rerender. Without seeing how that's implemented, we can't help you - but unless it's props or state or something derived from them then this won't work.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I updated the question with the code which updated the counter variable.

Comment: That's not really enough context to fully advise how to fix this, but enough to say that this is what you're doing wrong. React won't rerender a component just because a local variable has been updated. You need state for this, and to update it via the React API for doing so.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I will try your suggestion

Comment: Yeah counter should be made with `useState` so that changes to it will force re-renders

Comment: @PhantomSpooks What if the property has been created with useContext, will it trigger re-renders as well?

Answer (score 0):

As @Robin Zigmond and @PhantomSpooks pointed out, I changed

```
const keepImage = async () => {
 counter = counter + 1;
};
```

to

```
const keepImage = async () => {
 setCounter(counter + 1);
};
```

and now it works like a charm :)